# Caesar's code - problems in implementation in Python

Tags: python, ascii

Hello and thanks in advance for the answers,
I was trying to do first task for PythonChallenge:
http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/map.html
and I have a comuple of questions regarding the code.
I know that this code works:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
uletters = string.ascii_uppercase
text = ("g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.")
for x in range(0, 26):
    text = text.replace(letters[x-2], uletters[x])
    print(text.lower())
```

I was playing with the code a little bit and here are my observations in regard to which I have questions:
1. When I run:

```
text = text.replace(letters[x], uletters[x+2])
```

errors occur such as "trynslyte" instead of "translate". Why does this shift make such a change?
2. When I changed:
`uletters = string.ascii_uppercase` 
to

```
uletters = string.ascii_lowercase
```

a bunch of "z"s and "y"s appeared. Again, what is the matter?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you evaluate `letters[x-2]` and `x` is either 0 or 1, you end up with `letters[-1]` or `letters[-2]`, which in Python accesses the last and the penultimate elements, respectively. This is why this step works. However, indices that are greater than the index of the last element does not have the same effect, so `letters[x+2]` won't work when `x` is too big.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
letters[(x+2)%len(letters)]
```

To force this wrap-around.

Comment: Another approach is just to make `letters = string.ascii_lowercase * 2`

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is with `str.translate()`.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lc

text = ("g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. "
        "bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. "
        "sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj.")

print (text.translate(str.maketrans(lc, lc[2:] + lc[:2])))
```

To write an encoder, just swap the arguments to `maketrans()` around:

```
print (text.translate(str.maketrans(lc[2:] + lc[:2], lc)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with wraparound.  If x-2 is less than 0, you will get errors.

Comment: No, this direction is fine. It's when `x+2` is too big that is causing problems.

Comment: You are right.  I noticed it was a wraparound issue in general.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caeser_cipher#Example), the Caesar cipher is these two mathematical congruencies:

```
E_n(x) ≡ (x + n) mod 26
D_n(x) ≡ (x - n) mod 26
```

Where `E_n()` is the encryption algorithm, `D_n(x)` is the decryption algorithm, `x` is a bit of plain- or ciphertext, `n` is the key, and `26` is the size of the integer ring. So, the easiest way to write a program to perform the Caesar cipher is to... implement the above.

The only complication you will get with doing this on a computer is the fact that you are operating not on the integers `0` through `25`, but on two ranges of integers, because you are interpreting the integers as characters from the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) table. The upper case letters are the integers `65` through `90`, and the lower case letters are the integers `97` through `122`.

Luckily for you, python gives you two functions which convert ASCII characters to integers and back:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> chr(97)
'a'
```

You can utilize this to retain your cases. I'm going to pass the `ord`s in as defaults to arguments, but, ASCII isn't really going to change anytime soon. This does however let you encrypted different characters without changing the code.

```
def E(x, n, m=26, upper_ord=ord('A'), lower_ord=ord('a')):
    if x.isupper():
        return chr(((ord(x) - upper_ord + n) % m) + upper_ord)
    else:
        return chr(((ord(x) - lower_ord + n) % m) + upper_ord)

def D(x, n, m=26, upper_ord=ord('A'), lower_ord=ord('a')):
    return E(x, -n, m, upper_ord, lower_ord)

>>> E('b', 3)
'e'
>>> E('b', 25)
'a'
>>> E('b', -3)
'y'
>>> E('e', -3)
'b'
>>> E('Q', 15)
'F'
>>> plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> ciphertext = " ".join(map(lambda w: "".join(E(x, 2) for x in w), (word for word in 
sentence.split())))
>>> ciphertext
'Vjg swkem dtqyp hqz lworu qxgt vjg ncba fqi'
>>> decrypted = " ".join(map(lambda w: "".join(D(x, 2) for x in w), (word for word in 
ciphertext.split())))
>>> decrypted
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Using subindex offsets, in my opinion, is contrived. The mathematical formula is well-defined, so just use it!